# Angular unit test many view Child component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, viewchild, stepper

I have a component that contains several sub-components to make a wizard

```
<app-wizard>
  <cdk-step>
    <app-wizard-1></app-wizard-1>
  </cdk-step>
  <cdk-step>
    <app-wizard-2></app-wizard-2>
  </cdk-step>
</app-wizard>
```

So I have more viewChilds in my component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(WizardComponent) wizard!: WizardComponent;
  @ViewChild(Wizard1Component) wizardStep1!: Wizard1Component;
  @ViewChild(Wizard2Component) wizardStep2!: Wizard2Component;
  
  ....
}
```

I try to make unit test on my app component but the problem is that only the wizard sub-component is not null. The other 2 (wizardStep1 and wizardStep2) are null

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent, WizardComponent, Wizard1Component, Wizard2Component ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How do I ensure that all my components are not null?

And how to select the item

The WizardComponent component inherits from CdkStepper. But in unit test mode, the step list always remains at 0

Comment: You have a typo in 3rd @ViewChild, written "1" instead of "2".

Comment: I corrected but it doesn’t change anything. It works perfectly when I launch my application. By it is in my unit tests that it blocks

Comment: help me it is very important